# Add a "custom field" to a category that can be retrieved when viewing the category page with get_post_meta

Tags: php, categories, custom-field, post-meta

I usually set a custom field `customdata` for posts and pages, that I can obtain when rendering a page with this PHP code:

```
get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'customdata', true)
```

Is there a way to set a custom field `customdata` to category `mycat`, so that, when rendering the category view:

http://example.com/category/mycat

I can have access to `customdata` too from PHP code?

Comment: You have a option to add, update and get term meta as well, check [update_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/), [get_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/), [add_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/). The difference is when in category, the way to get the term id is `get_queried_object_id()`

Comment: Thank you @Buttered_Toast. I'd like my rendering code to work for a page, for a post, for a category, etc. Is there something that works for all types?  Does `get_post_meta(get_queried_object_id(), 'customdata', true)`  work for pages and posts as well?

Comment: Also @Buttered_Toast, I see no GUI textbox in the admin page "Edit category" to add a custom field. Can I do, once for all from PHP code in `add_action('init', ...`,  with `add_term_meta($categoryid, "customdata" , 'mydata');`?

Comment: `get_post_meta` works for all post_types, so pages and posts will work with that. category is a taxonomy so `get_post_meta` will not work for it, you will need to create so `if` logic that will check if you are in a post or category and run the appropriate function.

Comment: If you would like to visually see the metas I would suggest using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/), this plugin will create meta boxes for you based on your needs, it have some built in function to call that data as well. Will save you alot of headache

Comment: @Buttered_Toast I think you can post an answer with all this information from these different comments, I'll accept it! PS, if you have an example of code that tests if category / page / post, and queries the meta accordingly it would be great. PS2: I'm looking for a no-plugin solution.